# How to fix a TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list?

Tags: python, list

I am struggling with line 30 in the code below. `data[i]` is underlined and the returned list for `race_name` is blank. I don't understand why:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from datetime import date
race_name=[]
# To get the year date and month in the format I need
year=str(date.today())[0:4]
month=str(date.today())[5:7]
day=str(date.today())[9:11]
if int(day) < 10:
    day = "0"+day
if int(month) < 10:
    month = "0"+month
today_date = day + "/" + month + "/" + year
#Was trying a different method but couldnt find how to get meta data 
#and use it 
f1_schedule="https://www.formula1.com/en/racing/"+year+".html"
r = requests.get(f1_schedule)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html5lib')
# trying to make a list for all the race names
with open("f1_schedule","r") as file:
    data = file.readlines()
# loop to get each line, havent removed the parts that i dont need 
# but this dosent work so havent gone any farther
for i in range(24,len(data),22):
    race_name = race_name + data[i]
print(race_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your problem:

```
range(24,22)
```

In the REPL:

```
>>> [i for i in range(24, 22)]
[]
```

This iterates over an empty list, so `race_name` is never updated. Perhaps you want one of:

```
>>> [i for i in range(22, 24)]
[22, 23]
>>> [i for i in range(24, 22, -1)]
[24, 23]
```

Your second problem is that `race_name` is a `list`:

```
race_name = []
```

And the data you have is returning a `str`. You can't use the `+` to concatenate these two disparate types. Rather you need to use `append()`.

```
race_name.append(data[i])
```

Comment: thanks for the help but when i fixed the code a new error came                               
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list